# jQuery Dropdown Show/Hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I really don't know much about javascript, but I am trying to use the following code which works well. The problem I am having is if I add a "..." or ":" at the end of the "Choose" option, the code no longer works.

http://jsfiddle.net/fj63g/58/

HTML:

```
<select id="dropDown">
    <option>Choose</option>
    <option value="div1">Show Div 1</option>
    <option value="div2">Show Div 2</option>
</select>

<div id="div1" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 2</div>
```

Script:

```
$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();

$('#dropDown').change(function(){
$(this).find("option").each(function()
{
$('#' + this.value).hide();
});
    $('#' + this.value).show();

});
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();

$('#dropDown').change(function () {
    $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide()    
    $('#' + this.value).show();

});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48Mhd/)

OR

To fix your code, Just add `value=""` to the `Choose` option

```
<select id="dropDown">
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    <option value="div1">Show Div 1</option>
    <option value="div2">Show Div 2</option>
</select>
<div id="div1" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 2</div>
```

Here is an [updated fiddle fixing your code](http://jsfiddle.net/CDyZf/)

Comment: That is great - and much more simple! Thank you!

Comment: How do yoou go about adding a dropdown within the "drop-down-show-hide" with the same function as the main select?

Comment: You mean show a select option on choosing the outer select option ? @MauriceBotha

Comment: Yes that is what I meant and also got it right after playing around in fiddle.... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select id="dropDown">
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    <option value="div1">Show Div 1</option>
    <option value="div2">Show Div 2</option>
</select>

<div  id="div1" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 1</div>
<div  id="div2" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 2</div>
```

Script:

```
$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();

$('#dropDown').change(function(){
$(this).find("option").each(function()
{
    if (this.value != '')
    {
        $('#' + this.value).hide();
    }
});
$('#' + this.value).show();

});
```

The answer posted by karth is better, but this is so you can see what it was failing.

Ultimately, because you were telling it to hide an item that didn't exist, it was breaking on that line and not showing your divs.

The javascript was trying to resolve:

```
$('#' + undefined).hide();
```

It couldn't, thus would throw an error, and not display your divs.

Karth's answer is the most efficient, but you could also overcome it as shown above by providing a value to the "Choose" option and then checking for it when showing/hiding.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I definitely appreciate knowing why my code was not working.

Comment: No problem.  While getting an answer on how to do something is great and lets you fix the problem, getting some explanation on what broke it in the first place helps you avoid the problem again in the future.  ;0)

Answer (score 0):

Use it http://jsfiddle.net/fj63g/59/

```
$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();

$('#dropDown').change(function () {
    $('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();
    $('#' + this.value).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying this out from this fiddle
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fj63g/61/)

**html:**

```
<select id="dropDown">
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    <option value="div1">Show Div 1</option>
    <option value="div2">Show Div 2</option>
</select>

<div  id="div1" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 1</div>
<div  id="div2" class="drop-down-show-hide">div 2</div>
```

**js:**

```
$('.drop-down-show-hide').hide();

$('#dropDown').change(function(){
    $(this).find("option").each(function(){
        $("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
        console.log($(this));
    });    
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

it keeps the jquery styled syntax.

Answer (score -3):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
function namedata(data)
{
    if(data=='A')
    {
        $('#diva').css('display','block');
        $('#divb').css('display','none');
    }
    else if(data=='B')
    {
        $('#divb').css('display','block');
        $('#diva').css('display','none');
    }
}
</script>



<p><label>Choose Name</label>
        <select name="name" onchange="return namedata(this.value);">
            <option>-Select-</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
        </select>
        </p>

    <div style="display:none;" id="diva">My Div A</div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="divb">My Div B</div>
```

Comment: Please add some context as to why you think this solves the original Question, and ideally why it is better than the other answers

Comment: This code is simple and easy to understand.We can easily add more option in dropdown too